# How to inspect the objects loaded with data in R?

Tags: r, object, inspect

The kohonen package has a version of the wines data file (http://search.r-project.org/library/kohonen/html/wines.html) where it states

> A data frame containing 177 rows and thirteen columns; object vintages
>   contains the class labels. For compatibility with older versions of
>   the package, variable wine.classes is retained, too.

I have tried `str, attributes, ls, head, class, unclass`, but none of them allowed me to reveal those objects except the wines data.frame itself.

After loading I can see in RStudio the data (wines) and these 2 objects as Values (vintages, wine.classes).

What is the correct way to inspect these objects through the command line?

Regards

Joao

Comment: `wines` is a `matrix` class(wines). you can access the columns by `wines[,"alcohol"] ` for example. Or more conviently: `df <- as.data.frame(wines)`. Then  `str(df)`

str(df)

Comment: If you want to manually inspect a dataset in a spreadsheet like fashion, try `View(wines)`. Note the capital "V".

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, sorry, my bad. data(wines) loads more than the matrix/data.frame. These values I can see and use, the issue is the other 2 objects wine.classes and vintages that I know they are there because RStudio is showing them to me. What I want to know is how I would inspect an data loaded this way and be able to see that there were there 2 other objects. View(wines), just show the wines data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie I did not realize that data() is a loading process from a file: `data(<parameters>) Loads specified data sets, or list the available data sets.` That, I only got after an overview on the code of the "**data**" function itself and "then"going to check the manual :)

so far, please correct me If I'm wrong, I see 2 ways of knowing what "**data**" loads,

1. Load the package and then load the dataset in a new or well known environment and use `ls()`, there You can see the new objects after the load;
2. Before loading the dataset, but after loading the package, We can use `help(datasetname)`, and hope they are well and clearly described there.